# MySQL DATETIME group

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I want to group records in hour or day.

The table A looks like:
The table A has two columns: ID int, record_time datetime,

For example, two records looks like:

```
id  record_time
-----------------------
1   2011-01-24 22:14:50
2   2011-01-24 22:14:50
```

I want to group by hour. I use command:

```
select * 
from A 
group by Hour(record_time);
```

However, it does not output as I want.
It only outputs the first record. The second record does not show.

Comment: Provide an example of your expected output.

Comment: If you want to group by hour, and the hour is the same in both, you will only get one record. That's what the group by is for. What response do you expect?

Comment: I misunderstand "group by". Yes, use group by I can only get one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM A 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record_time, '%H')
```

UPDATE

```
SELECT *
FROM A 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(record_time, '%H%Y%m%d')
```

Try this... just ORDER BY (no grouping)

Comment: It stills outputs "1   2011-01-24 22:14:50".

Comment: It stills only output '1   2011-01-24 22:14:50'. I want to output two records.

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(record_time, '%Y%m%d%H') FROM A GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(record_time, '%H')  ----- This should format the list of items to YearMonthDayHour and group them by Hour... See update above...

Answer (score 1):

What you call grouping sounds like it's actually *sorting*. Change `group by` to `order by` and see if that gets you what you want. If by "group" you actually mean "I want to group the rows *together in the result set*, this is what you need (and is called ordering).

Answer (score 0):

you should use [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), like

```
group by date_format(record_time, '%Y%m%d%H');
```

Comment: yeah, don't just telling us is not working, update your question with your expecting output ...